# Create and store/add to an array from filtered checkbox values

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a scenario where a long list of checkbox options are **filtered** in and out with a PHP/ajax query. So when a user checks one or more check boxes, the need is to create a list of what boxes the user has checked.

Using jQuery and .map(), I am able to create the initial list array of what checkboxes are checked. Easy enough.

```
var selected_checkboxes;

$( document ).on( 'click', '.checkbox_select', function() {
    var checkbox_selector = $( '.checkbox_select:checked' );

    selected_checkboxes = checkbox_selector.map( function(i, n) {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    console.log(selected_checkboxes);
});
```

So here, we'll say I have a group of 10 checkboxes (Checkbox 1 - 10) and I check the first 3.

**Console output** `["Checkbox 1", "Checkbox 2", "Checkbox 3"]`

The **problem** comes when you filter the view of checkboxes. Say you **filter** out all checkboxes other than Checkbox 3, 5 and 6. Checkbox 3 is still checked. Now if we check "Checkbox 5", our new list array will be as follows: `["Checkbox 3", "Checkbox 5"]`.

I know why it does that, but the needed result is to build upon what was previously checked prior to running the filter, which should look like `["Checkbox 1", "Checkbox 2", "Checkbox 3", "Checkbox 5"]`. Almost like you're just adding to that initial array of values.

The checkboxes when filtered can't be hidden with hide/show since it's all an ajax based query.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could get an array to work like this? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
var selected_checkboxes = [];
   $("input:[type = 'checkbox']").click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        selected_checkboxes.push($(this));
    }else{
        var index = selected_checkboxes.indexOf($(this));
        if (index != -1) {
            selected_checkboxes = selected_checkboxes.slice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
for(var i = 0; i< selected_checkboxes.length;i++){
    console.log(selected_checkboxes[i].val());
}
```

please try!

Answer (score 0):

Here chekedid is your input type check-box class name

```
function selectedMychecbox() {
    checkedid = Array();
    $('.checkedid:checked').each(function () {
        checkedid.push($(this).val());
    });


}
```